# Android Maven Plugin and flavors

Tags: android, maven, android-build, android-maven-plugin

Does someone know if it's possible, and in which extent, to build different app flavors using the Android Maven Plugin ?

I just saw there was a [rename manifest package](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html#renameManifestPackage) option in the aapt goal (read in this [excellent blog article](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/apk-mojo.html#renameManifestPackage) btw).

Are there any limitations to create 2 flavors of an app if you combine this and some usual maven profiles techniques ? Is there any example somewhere ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I have used profiles to achieve this but I have to say that the Gradle flavors are superior in  2 points:

**Context**

let's say you want to have 2 app with different drawables so you have 2 res folder

1. Gradle flavor will use the default folders and overwrite anything that comes from the flavor into the default.
2. Flavors can be build in 1 command into diff directories

Maven partial example:

```
<profile>
    <id>winter-resources</id>
    <properties>
        <android.res.dir>${project.basedir}/winter-res</android.res.dir>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

and in the configuration of the android-maven-plugin you would put

```
<resourceDirectory>${android.res.dir}</resourceDirectory>
```

Comment: Do you have any maven example ? Something that could help to compare with Gradle would be a plus, but still could provide a working example for a maven setup ?

Comment: Edited it. the pom is from a closed source project but if you need more help just shoot

Comment: Btw I reviewed Gradle and I'm still sticking with maven right now as aar support is in the new 3.8.1-SNAPSHOT. I couldn't make gradle work with sonar what a pitty and had some issues with jenkins but I gotta look more on it later. I love the performance boost gradle has over android-maven but that might change once we refactor android-maven to use AndroidBuilder

Comment: Your performance boost is surprising, I just switched to Maven because Gradle was soooo slow to do its forced full-rebuild every time and lack of good Intellij support (they're trying but it's still not there yet).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bable5/maven-android-flavors/blob/master/pom.xml

I found a pom example using profiles for flavors.