# Is it possible to mimick gradle build flavours with maven?

Tags: java, maven

Let's say I have a main class with some calls in the main method:

```
public void basicInit() {...}

public void loadExtraFeature1() {...}

public void loadExtraFeature2() {...}

public void loadExtraFeature3() {...}
```

ExtraFeature1, ExtraFeature2, ExtraFeature3 are all located in separate class files.

I know that during maven build, I can control the process to leave those classes out of the jar file, but the main method will still contain these 3 feature loading calls.

Is there a way to add some tag or parameter that will instruct maven to not include lines between those tags in the built java class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Maven Plugin and flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917762/android-maven-plugin-and-flavors)

Comment: Well, it's not an android application, just a java application, but I'll check it out. The main goal is the same more or less.